# Jquery UI Datepicker keeps asking to be filled in upon selection with cursor and on submit

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I ran into this problem and can't seem to find an answer so far ...
I have a form that has 2 text inputs with JQuery UI datepicker

```
<input id="datepicker_pickup" name="pickup_date" type="text" required>
<input id="datepicker_dropoff" name="dropoff_date" type="text" required>
```

In my head section I properly reference the JQuery and JQuery UI scripts.

Then, at the bottom of the page just before the BODY end tag, I have the following:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker_pickup").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", 
        minDate: 0 
    }).val();

    $("#datepicker_dropoff").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", 
        minDate: 0 
    }).val();      
});
```

I select the date in the first input with the cursor and click the SUBMIT button. I get a tooltip telling me that the datepicker field must be filled in, even though it has value in it. However, if - after selecting it with the cursor - I just delete one digit from the date and type it again, it will NOT warn me anymore.

Any insight greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same `id` for the pickers. Change to:

```
<input id="datepicker_pickup" name="pickup_date" type="text" required>
<input id="datepicker_dropoff" name="pickup_date" type="text" required>
```

Comment: My bad, sorry I just copied and paste, of course I am using different IDs. Sorry. Just changed it.

Answer (score 0):

anyone has some ideas ? I am using html5 doctype and it appears that upon datepicker selection, the field doesn't get or "keep" the value, otherwise I wouldn't get the warning. Upon request I could provide the entire code of the page, maybe there's some conflicts with other JS in the page. This is driving me crazy because I can't submit the form unless I remove the "required" attributes of the two datepickers. Thank you.

UPDATE
I found out that datepicker fields were conflicting with this script :
[CIVEM 0.0.7](https://github.com/javanto/civem.js) which is a custom validation script that I was using to localize the input error messages. It was nice and would have been perfect but with it my form cannot be submitted so I removed it, now it works.

SOLVED
I got help from hannu, the developer of CIVEM and it appears that indeed CIVEM conflicts with the datepicker UNLESS some code is added to the datepicker so that an onInput event is fired.

I have replaced the code with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#datepicker_pickup").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", minDate: 0, onSelect: function() {
    this.oninput({target: this});
}}).val();
$("#datepicker_dropoff").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", minDate: 0, onSelect: function() {
    this.oninput({target: this});
}}).val();
```

});

and it is now working fine. Kudos to Hannu for his help.